# Getting error while creating peyment(Stripe)

Tags: request, stripe-payments, postman

I'm using this code to create payment(Stripe) in the tab Pre-request script

```
pm.sendRequest({
url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer pk_test_...',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
},
data: {
    'card[number]': 2223003122003222,
    'card[exp_month]': 12,
    'card[exp_year]': 2020,
    'card[cvc]': 123
}
```

And getting this error:

> You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY').

everything works as a separate request

Comment: is the key used, correct?

Comment: Have you tried with `header` rather than `headers`? Also, is that syntax in the example correct?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had my dotenv import come after I was calling my secret key.

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
require ("dotenv").config();
```

Reversing those two lines of code was what I needed to do.

```
require ("dotenv").config();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
```

Comment: This works for me too, I wonder why it would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something like this:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer pk_test_......',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        urlencoded: [
            { key: "card[number]", value: 2223003122003222 },
            { key: "card[exp_month]", value: 12 },
            { key: "card[exp_year]", value: 2020 },
            { key: "card[cvc]", value: 123 },
        ]
    }
})
```

Your issue was around the `headers` key as it should be `header`. Also, the way the payload was written seemed like it would error(?). I tried this code locally and saw the response back from Stripe.

You might want to change the token credentials now that you've posted it here.

Comment: thx. stupid mistake on my part.
Test account has this token credentials. not scary. But i will fix it now

Comment: Did my answer give you enough information to solve your issue?